# Order two different C# lists with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have two C# (3.5) types that are different from each other. I do not control them so I can not make them inherit from a common type or implement an interface. But they are very similar in "shape":

```
class A
{
string Name
string Data
}

class B
{
string Title
string OtherStuff
}

class C
{
string ID
string ExtendedData
}

List< A > myAList
List< B > myBList
```

I would like to do the following with a LINQ query:

Return all the elements in lists `myAList` and `myBList` ordered by `Name` or `Title` (whatever applies) the result must be a `List< C >` where `ID = Name` or `Title` and `ExtendedData = Data` or `OtherStuff`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var myCList = (myAList.Select(a => new C
    { ID = a.Name, ExtendedData = a.Data })
    .Union(myBList.Select(b => new C
        { ID = b.Title, ExtendedData = b.OtherStuff }))
    .OrderBy(c => c.ID)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Chris, thanks for the answer. Just one note:

You need an extra set of parenthesis:

( myAList...b.OtherStuff }) ).OrderBy(c=>c.ID) 

or the OrderBy will not apply to the full new list.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = (
    from a in myAList
    select new C { ID = a.Name, ExtendedData = a.Data }
).Union(
    from b in myBList
    select new C { ID = b.Title, ExtendedData = b.OtherStuff } 
).OrderBy(e => e.ID).ToList();
```